# Handling large number of async tasks in short time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, intentservice

I need to call a lot of xmlrpc requests in particular order (four of them). I'm using async task for each one and that is OK, but it seems to be lot of code and reading/writing to files and I put all those async's in one intent service. Problem is when i need to call intent multiple times in a short period of time and I can't cancel or stop Async task easily. I know I probably shouldn't use intent service for that purpose so please tell me whats the best solution for handling a large number of async tasks?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the of of intent service and how it is called?

Comment: I can't now. It doesn't matter how it's called:)
Let's just say that when all async's finish, intent service notifies broadcas receiver in activity that it has finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only limited number of asynctasks (
from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/os/AsyncTask.java#AsyncTask))

```
private static final int CPU_COUNT = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT + 1;
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT * 2 + 1;
private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 1;
```

So it's better to use only intent service with it. Maybe you can store your intents/requests in collection and cancel/stop them in service?

Or maybe you can use Volley? It enables canceling requests from the queue.

Comment: can I combine xmlrpc and volley? I'm using xmlrpc-android library

Answer (score 0):

use Loaders ( http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html )

You can stop them when you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Loaders.
If you must use API below that support loaders - just include support library in your project.
Loaders are the same like AsynkTasks but more improved and can catch many errors. You could avoid many troubles when using them.

Comment: @File You can create static boolean variable in IntentService. Every time in thread you must check it. When the time comes - just call return in onHandleIntent.

Comment: If I need to call same Intent Service once again within the time when it hasn't finished yet, then I set boolean to false and service stops...the problem is when I call service again that boolean is still false.

Comment: What about singleInstance class? Save your boolean variables about IntentService there and you can know status everywhere.